# Issue regarding dynamically created object in c++

Tags: c++

I was asked to make a project on the phonebook using BST in c++. So I have made class "BstDetails" which has all the relevant information needed and made another class "PhoneBook" where I implement the insert, deletion, etc functions. "Phonebook" is actually also the friend class of "BstDetails". So in class "PhoneBook", I call the function "create" to make a new entry in the phonebook. I dynamically create object but I am confused about how will I actually assign input data to entries of the object. Can someone guide me?

```cpp
#include<iostream>                                                                                                                             
#include<string>                                                                                                                               
using namespace std;                                                                                                                           
class BstDetails{                                                                                                                              
  private:                                                                                                                                     
  string name;                                                                                                                                 
  long number;                                                                                                                                 
  BstDetails* left;                                                                                                                            
  BstDetails* right;                                                                                                                           
  friend class PhoneBook;                                                                                                                      
  public:                                                                                                                                      
  BstDetails(){                                                                                                                                
    left=NULL;                                                                                                                                 
    right=NULL;                                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                            
};                                                                                                                                             
class PhoneBook{                                                                                                                               
  private:                                                                                                                                     
  BstDetails* root;                                                                                                                            
  public:                                                                                                                                      
  PhoneBook(){                                                                                                                                 
    root=NULL;                                                                                                                                 
  }                                                                                                                                            
  void create(BstDetails name , BstDetails number){                                                                                            
    if(root==NULL){                                                                                                                            
      BstDetails* data=new BstDetails();                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                               
};
```

Comment: from the looks of it you are trying to create a Doubly linked list.. why are the arguments of create method of BstDetails type, name should be string and number should be of long type.. Since your Phonebook class is a friend class you should be able to access private methods as data->name=name, data->number=number.

Comment: Make a smarter constructor that accepts the values you with to set as parameters and then sets the appropriate members to those values. I like to use the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to make this easier.

Comment: Phonebook contains type BstDetails, yet you are making Phonebook a friend of BstDetails. Something design wise is wrong here, and there shouldn't be some sort of circular "dependency" here

Comment: @OmidCompSCI has a good point and I would go a bit further.I would separate the BST from the contents. That way you can write and test the BST and Details logic separately (almost always easier to write and test one thing at a time) and you can reuse the BST code later to hold other data.

Comment: Seems like name/number should be members of PhoneBook and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BstDetails` constructor should be passed `name` and `number`

```
public:                                                                                                                                      
    BstDetails(const std::string& n, long num) :
    left(nullptr),
    right(nullptr)
    name(n),
    number(num)
    {
    }
```

Your `create` method on phonebook takes similar parameters and returns a `BstDetails`

```
BstDetails* create(const std::string& name, long number){
    return new BstDetails(name, number);
}
```

So `create` is just a thin wrapper around `new`, so you may consider not needing that helper function.

But you could build up a `create` method such as this the following that creates a node and inserts into the tree

```
void create(const std::string& name, long number) {

    BstDetails* node = new BstDetails(name, number);
    BstDetails** ppParent = &root;
    BstDetails* parent = *ppParent;

    while (parent) {
        ppParent = (node->name < parent->name) ? &(parent->left) : &(parent->right);
        parent = *ppParent;
    }

    *ppParent = node;
}
```